# How can I improve the speed of scanning multiple directories recursively at the same?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-programming

So I am trying to speed up my program by using concurrency and/or multi-threading and/or process parallelism. The topics are pretty complex and I am sort of new to them so I am still trying to figure out which one to use and when.

My task (rather sub-task):

1. Get size of a UNIX directory (recursively). In fact, I will be processing multiple directories at once.

Based on what I understand, scanning directory is I/O bound process, and, as a result, decided to use threading instead of multiple processes.

Here is what I tried (functions work but the results are not really what I expect):

**My dircetory scanning function - utils.py:**

```
def get_path_size(path):
    """Returns total size of a file/directory.

    Args:
        path: File/directory path.

    Returns:
        Total size of a path in bits.

    """
    # Size in bytes/bits (B).
    total = 0

    if os.path.isdir(path):
        with os.scandir(path) as direc:
            for entry in direc:
                if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
                    total += get_path_size(entry.path)
                else:
                    total += entry.stat(follow_symlinks=False).st_size
    else:
        total += os.stat(path).st_size

    return total
```

**Here is my multi-threaded function that calls the function above - file1.py:**

```
import concurrent.futures

def conc(self):
    reqs = [{'path': '/path/to/disk1'}, {'path': '/path/to/disk2'}]

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=12) as executor:
        future_to_path = {
            executor.submit(utils.get_path_size, req['path']): req for req in reqs
        }

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_path):
            path = future_to_path[future]
            size = future.result()
            print(path, size)
```

**And here is my function using process parallelism - file2.py:**

```
import concurrent.futures

def paral():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
            for path, size in zip(PATHS, executor.map(get_path_size, PATHS)):
                    print(path, size)
```

The reason why I am having doubts is because it seems that program finishes faster (if not faster, then about the same) using `ProcessPoolExecutor` rather than `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Based on my understanding that `get_path_size()` is rather I/O intensive and [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) saying that `ThreadPoolExecutor` is more suited for I/O work, I find it surprising that `paral()` runs faster.

My questions:

1. Am I doing it right overall? I mean, should I be using `ProcessPoolExecutor` or `ThreadPoolExecutor`?
2. Any other suggestions on how to make this code better/faster etc.?

**Edit #1 - Test results:**

I ran 5 tests for each of the 3 options (each test was ran one after another on a non-loaded machine): non-parallel, `ProcessPoolExecutor`, and `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Total size of all directories was 65GB in this testing. Yesterday, I ran these tests on directories with total size of ~1.5TB and the results were pretty much the same, relatively.

Machine spec:

```
CPU(s):                20
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    10
Socket(s):             2
```

Non-parallel run-times:

```
Duration 38.25443077087402 seconds
Duration 16.98011016845703 seconds
Duration 21.282278299331665 seconds
Duration 37.90052556991577 seconds
Duration 40.511338233947754 seconds
```

`ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```
Duration 7.311123371124268 seconds
Duration 15.097688913345337 seconds
Duration 15.133012056350708 seconds
Duration 13.949966669082642 seconds
Duration 4.563556671142578 seconds
```

`ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
Duration 28.408297300338745 seconds
Duration 7.303474187850952 seconds
Duration 26.91611957550049 seconds
Duration 4.6026129722595215 seconds
Duration 3.424044370651245 seconds
```

Comment: My gut instinct in this situation is that you cannot do any optimization unless you work on OS or even HW layer. Maybe try to find OS APIs that could be used to call that would return the size of the whole directory, instead of doing it yourself? This would give OS way to use it's own optimizations.

Comment: @DocBrown I added test results

Comment: @tera_789: the test results don't seem to support what you wrote in your question - for 2 of them, `ProcessPoolExecutor` is faster, but for 3 of them, `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @DocBrown yeah I see that...it fluctuates a lot...hard to make a decision thus. At this point, I am starting to think that either network or storage device's OS is playing a big role here...sometimes it is `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which is faster in most tests, and, sometimes it is `ProcessPoolExecutor`...

Comment: @DocBrown The thing is that CPU usage never goes really high when I run these scans (it is mostly 20-30%), sometimes even less.

Comment: @tera_789: the CPU usage you observe is a typical characteristic of an I/O bound problem, not very astonishing.

Comment: On a physical hard drive seek time is not only a function of where the file is physically located, but also where the head was before you asked for it. Keep in mind you're likely not the only thing moving the head. To see how much this is impacting you set up a ram disk and test against that. Should stabilize your variance (and be orders of magnitude faster). Doesn't solve the problem but it makes clear where it lies.

Answer (score 4):

First thing to understand is that threading **is** a form of parallelism. The differences between separate threads and separate processes are not all that important *in this case*.

As you write yourself, this is a heavily I/O bound process. In fact so heavily that the code running in between the I/O access will not have any measurable impact. As such, you will not expect to find a huge difference between different approaches to parallelism. But since you are asking, ThreadPoolExecutor will allocate five times as many workers as ProcessPoolExecutor. Since all of those workers just cause overhead for no actual gain (you're still limited by the I/O going over just one or two disks), ProcessPoolExecutor will be at a slight advantage. (Try reducing the number of workers, and I think, the difference will go away).

The only way to profit from parallelism in your use case would be if you can split the I/O workload across several hard disks / storage devices, where you would use one thread / process per device.

Comment: I reduced the number of workers to 12 (previously it was 24) but nothing really changed...I also posted test results if you wanna take a look...

Comment: And, the I/O workload is actually already split across different HDs and storage devices

Comment: How many disks? That will be much more important to know than how many CPUs. I would expect optimum results with one thread per disk (**and** making sure that each thread works on exactly one disk). Also your timings show a *huge* amount of fluctuation. I do wonder why. Is this network bound? Are other tasks running on this system during your benchmarking?

Comment: It is sort of hard to tell how many disks exactly because the pool of disks is tens of thousands and the data blocks may be spread across those. Also, there could be network limitations based on the load and there are QOS policies on each storage device. On top of that, each storage device is intelligent enough to give certain priority to different processes...In terms of network, this is where I expected `ThreadPoolExecutor` to excel more than others.

Comment: Fluctuations in run-time duration do seem weird even to me, which makes me think of QOS etc. because machine was completely free from other tasks.

Comment: Phew. I do think you'll have to tell quite a few more details about your setup. Obviously it involves networking, which, indeed will introduce a whole new layer to look at (and probably much more important than the details of parallelism on the controlling machine). Further: Tens of thousands of disks? Are we talking about *physical* disks, there? Cause *that* is what will matter.

Comment: Also, are you making sure that each (physical) disk has a single worker assigned to it? Two workers on the same disk will not be able to actually get much done in parallel. Good/bad luck in the distribution of your workers might explain some of the fluctuation in your timings.

Comment: Yes, thousands of physical disks. I knew that networking 'issue' could be there but was hopeful that `ThreadPoolExecutor` would help.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure which workers and how many are assigned to what disks. How could I even check that?

Comment: Good question. However to test whether this is actually the relevant figure, try feeding your algorithm with a) tasks that are each on separate physical disks (and separate physical network devices) and b) tasks that are all on one disk / device. Of course each single tasks should be roughly the same size, to make the measurements comparable.

Comment: Oh, and you're really interested in per disk total usage, not per subdirectory usage, right? In that case, using df (via os.system()) will be **a lot** faster, than calculating directory size, recursively.

Comment: @tera_789: I would recommend you edit the details about the storage hardware into your question (in the comments here below chances are high they will be overlooked)..

Comment: @Tfry I actually need sub-directory size so `df` won't help

Answer (score 2):

Having some activity formally I/O bound doesn't imply it can't be parallelized. As a radically marginal but expressive example, consider you have to read something from tape drivers, and a tape seek is average 5 minutes. You have to read something from two different tapes, each installed into own driver (device). If you issue requests in parallel, you'll get average time approximately 5 minutes. If to issue requests one after other, result time is 10 minutes.

If I got it right, your case is for the same request set but in a single process instead of different processes. At a glance, I'd suspect that kernel I/O scheduler differentiates threads and processes, and provides some kind of I/O bandwidth limiting with a bucket per process. Another variant is that your implementation spends too much for proper transition between Python and C land. But all these are just speculations without real facts.

The problem is that performance is really hard. Folks are spending man years to tune their code and to find a tiny detail that affects all or, vice versa, to rewrite entire layers to achieve 1-2% speedup. And, after that, next change in subordinated layers (CPU, kernel, etc.) can void all these results. So, if you see difference less that, say, 30%, just select the variant you see the best for now and switch to another task :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a warning: You are measuring your execution time, apparently with no other code running at the same time. But you're not on your own. You also need to consider how you affect other code running on the same hardware. If running tasks in parallel gives you halved execution time while quadrupling total network traffic, that's not a good solution because everyone else suffers.

And of course nobody cares how long it takes if you do it *once*. Therefore I'd try to figure out if there are ways to cache data so that the total work done on consecutive runs is less.

Comment: Good point but this is a dedicated hardware so I am not really worried about others doing something else on this machine. Caching data may not be required because directory sizes change frequently.